# Conceptual approach for task queue pool

Tags: celery, message-queue, distributed, atomic

Suppose I had a distributed task queue for processing emails. Each email needed to be fetched and parsed created a new job in the queue.

Now the email provider is rate limited to n number of concurrent connections per email account, so when I worker would start a task, it would obtain a "connection" (by connection I just mean something to account for the fact that there's now n-1 available connections for other workers to access that account). If no connections were free, the worker would return the job to the broker and proceed to try the next job.

I attempted to solve this with atomic locks, the worker would first have to acquire the lock before it could access the pool of connections, but ran into a thundering herd problem - where the workers sometimes hit it just right that 2 workers could acquire the lock simultaneously throwing off the count and exceeding the rate limit.

Is there a more elegant approach to this type of situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are two ways to solve this:

1. You have 1 service which will handle the lock-count. This way you can lock the access to the atomic lock itself within the program code as well, and make sure that the maximum number of locks won't ever be exceeded.
2. When you want a distributed way to give away the connections, without an elected leader, the only other way, which I know to do this, would be the [Paxos algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_%28computer_science%29).